# Pagination not working on my application - CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have been able to develop a pagination for my page which contains about 25000 records. The page paginates in 100's but for now, when i click on the pagination link to move to the next page, it leads me to the first page again.  But the URI on my browser shows the `per page number` like  `customers/100` . What could i be doing wrong below

**Controller**

```
    $config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'customers/index/';
    $config["total_rows"] = $customers
    $config["per_page"] = 100;
    $config['num_links'] = 10;
    $config["uri_segment"] = 3;

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;

    $data['items'] = $this->customer->get_customer_all($config["per_page"]);
```

**Model**

```
public function get_customer_all($limit = null) {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('courses');           

        if($limit!=''){
            $this->db->limit($limit);
         }
        $query  = $this->db->get();

        return ($query) ? $query->result() : false;
    }
```

Comment: Have a look at [the manual](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=limit#limiting-or-counting-results) about `limit()`. Currently, you're only adding the limit, not the offset, which means that the database will return the same records on all pages. I would also recommend you to have an `orderBy()` as well. Don't trust that the database always will return the data sorted in the same way if you don't explicitly set the sort order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you not use `$page` variable?
For getting data partially you need both `limit` and `offset`.
`limit` for count of customers per page and `offset` for understanding what page you are on.

So try to change you request to model like this:

```
$data['items'] = $this->customer->get_customer_all($config["per_page"], $page);
```

And update model like this (with some changes):

```
public function get_customer_all($limit = 0, $offset = 0) {
    return $this->db->select('*')->
                      from('courses')->
                      limit($limit)->
                      offset($offset)->
                      get()->
                      result_array();
}
```